# Interpreting GPS info of exif data from many photos in python

Tags: python, gps, exif

The above code could extract coordinates from a specific photo, how can I make it able to extract data from every photo existing in the directory?

```
from GPSPhoto import gpsphoto
data= gpsphoto.getGPSData('IMG_1.JPG')
print(data['Latitude'], data['Longitude'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```py
from GPSPhoto import gpsphoto
import os
path = "C:/Users/pythonproject" #path to image folder
for i in os.listdir(path):
  data = gpsphoto.getGPSData(os.path.join(path,i))
  print(i,data['Latitude'], data['Longitude'])
```

Make sure all your paths have "/" in them. You may have put at "" in a path without realizing it. so e.x "C:/Windows" instead of "C:\Windows"

Comment: Dear @Seth, thanks for your response, but I got the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Science/pythonProject3/gps.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(i,data['Latitude'], data['Longitude'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I got now the following error:

  File " C:/Users/Science/pythonProject3/gps.py", line 3
    path = 'C:/Users/Science/pythonProject3/' #path to image folder
          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: @Sam If your interested in unicode escape characters I recommend you check out [Build your own Command Line with ANSI escape codes](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html)

Comment: Make sure all your paths have "/" in them.  You may have put at "\" in a path without realizing it. so e.x "C:/Windows" instead of "C:\Windows".

Comment: Thank you so much. I fixed the problem by doubling the backslashes ...

Comment: No problem! Make sure to mark the answer as correct so other people can find it!

Happy Coding!